# mean value theorem for vector functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations

I was reading the following theorem from Rudin, but I can't get my head around the proof.

Given $f: \mathbb{E}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m,$ where $\mathbb{E}\subset\mathbb{R}^n $ is a convex open set and where $\mid\mid f'({\bf x}) \mid\mid \le M$, show that $$\mid f({\bf b })-f({\bf a})\mid\le M\mid {\bf b}-{\bf a} \mid.$$

The solution in the book considers $\ \gamma(t)=(1-t)\cdot{\bf a}+t\cdot {\bf b}$ and $\ g(t)=f(\gamma(t)).$ Then $$g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))({\bf b-a)} ,$$ where $f'$ represents a linear transformation. My understanding is that this relation is a composition of linear mappings, but the next step in the proof is $$ \mid g'(t)\mid \le \mid\mid f'(\gamma (t)) \mid\mid \  \mid {\bf b-a}\mid\le M\mid{\bf b-a}\mid,$$ which finishes the proof. In this case we regarded ${\bf( b-a)}$ as an $\it input$ vector for $f'$ , and not as a composition of linear maps ???.

In another book, where a particular case was trated,i.e. $f:E\rightarrow R \ , $ they write further:
 $$g'(t)(h)=h\cdot g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)(h)=\ldots= h\cdot f'(\gamma(t))({\bf b-a)}$$ and so $$ g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))({\bf b-a)}$$ and this is a linear map applied to a vector.
Is this what's meant in Rudin? How should I think of this? Thak you.

Answer (score 2):

For each $\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f'(\mathbf{p})$ is a linear map. In particular, $f'\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)$ is a linear map. Therefore, it has a norm. And, by the definition of the norm of linear map,$$\bigl\|f'\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})\bigr\|\leqslant\bigl\|f'\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\bigr\|.\|\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\|.$$

Comment: And in this particular case, we have $LHS=\mid f(b)-f(a)\mid$ and $\mid \mid  {\bf b-a} \mid \mid$ is a linear map that takes a vector $v$ and outputs the dot product ${\bf (b-a)} . v $ ?

Comment: @DanLeonte I don't know what you mean by $\bigl|f(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})\bigr|$; $f(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})$ is a vector, not a scalar. And $\|\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\|$ is *not* a linear map. It's just the norm of $\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: @Carlos Santos  thank you for your comments. Sorry for my last post. I was a bit sloppy. I What I wanted to ask actually is : 
 in the equation ,$$g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))({\bf b-a)} ,$$, ${\bf b-a}$ is a linear map that does the  scalar product of ${\bf b-a}$ with $v$, right? thus, it s norm $\mid \mid {\bf b-a}\mid \mid $ is the modulus of the vector ${\bf(b-a)}$

Comment: @DanLeonte No. $\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}$ is just a vector.

Comment: Any idea about why would someone downvote my answer?

Comment: I presume I was the only one who voted, and there is an upvote. But probably this is not that important..... I am stilll confused whether this equation is the actual chain rule, in which  we have a composition of linear maps, or whether it s just a matrix/vector multiplication. Thank you.

Comment: @DanLeonte It's neither. It's the image of a vector by a linear map. The vector is $\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}$ and the linear map is $f'\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)$.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your trouble would be not knowing that we can identify a linear map with a matrix. So the chain rule involving linear maps can be written in a form of products of matrices. You can check  Apostol's Mathematical Analysis to see all the details as he makes it very clear in that book. To get a feeling of the thing, note that $b-a$ is a vector but $x \mapsto (b-a)x$ is a linear map.

Rudin does not (and no need indeed, as context usually helps prevent confusion) notaionally distinguish a linear map from a matrix. If it helps, in the Rudin's proof you can view $f'(\gamma(t))$ as the Jacobian matrix of $f'$ at $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: I thought I could see this as a composition of linear 
 maps $g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))({\bf b-a)} ,$ where all 3 functions here are linear maps , and then  write it for a particular argument $h$ 
 $$g'(t)(h)=h\cdot g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)(h)=\ldots= h\cdot f'(\gamma(t))({\bf b-a)}$$ and so $$ g'(t)=f'(\gamma(t))({\bf b-a)}$$ and this is a vector = a linear map applied to a vector. Is this a good way of looking at it, or at least a correct one? THanks